# Adding javax.servlet.jsp.jstl lib to project gives glassfish/Payara deploy error

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, payara

Im trying to deploy spring project into glassfish 6/Payara server.

when i add javax.servlet.jsp.jstl into lib directory it gives me this error :

[image]

Im using  :

JDK 17,
Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0),
Glassfish 6,
Eclipse Payara plugin

Changing to org.glassfish.web » javax.servlet.jsp.jstl » 1.2.5 still gives same error.

Also if i add servlet config to web.xml the error happens too :

[image]

Comment: Does it deploy with servers other than Payara?

Comment: @nitind yes. i have no problem if i switch to tomcat 9.